# mat-optgroup not working with compareWith

Tags: angular, typescript

when using groups I get undefined on x2 in my compareWith but removing the group works fine. What I am missing here? why does not compareWith work when having mat-optgroup?

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Products</mat-label>
      <mat-select [compareWith]="compareWith">
        <mat-optgroup
          *ngFor="let group of productGroups"
          [label]="group.name"
        >
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of group.Items" [value]="item">
            {{ item.productName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

```
  compareWith(x1: any, x2: any): boolean {
    console.log('compareWith', x1, x2); // When using groups x2 is undefined
    return x1.id == x2.id
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (x2: any) is undefined since you are not initializing the select nor binding (using either ngModel or formControl) so the compareWith directive doesn't have something to compare with